I need a temporary hoist and track system to lift a dead chest freezer up through a tight stairwell
I want to rig a temporary wooden frame in a stairwell strong enough to support a hoist rail channel (for an electric winch) so I can lift a small chest freezer (I'm guessing it's about 200-250 lbs) up a narrow staircase with a 90° corner. The trouble is, I need the hoist to lift it high enough so it can be manoeuvred around the corner because of the tight clearance. It can't be done below a certain height, so I need a winch to assist the haulers in lifting it high enough. I can tie vertical support 2x4s to the walls directly to the studs to use as anchor points for a centre beam to which I'll attach the hoist C-Track rail.
How much weight will a 2x4 hold along an 8' span either horizontally or on edge? Bear in mind, it needs to be strong enough to prevent failure (safety for the haulers) but only needs to last long enough for one lift. Then it'll be dismantled. Thanks.




Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Is this the only exit from the basement?

If it got in there, then unless the building has been modified since then, it can be gotten out.
They probably did not use fancy winch and rail systems to bring it in, just strong guys with experience and a refrigerator cart, which is basically a hand-truck with treads to help it move up and down stairs. In extreme cases, there are hand trucks with built-in powered lifts to move them from step to step; these are used when 600 lb safes have to be moved.
Hiring somebody more experienced, better equipped, and in better condition to handle it is almost certainly safer and easier than trying to homebrew a solution. And might not be much more expensive, especially if you figure the possible cost of things going wrong.
I am assuming that you want to move this intact. If you are taking it out of service, then @dfphoto has a valid point; by stripping off the door and any other easily removable parts, you can significantly reduce the weight,  even if you don't go as far as trying to remove parts of the cooling system. And many municipalities will want you to dismount the door anyway before disposing of a refrigerator, to reduce the risk of a kid getting trapped inside and suffocating. Cutting should not be necessary, just removing some screws.
(Actually, even if you want to keep it intact, temporarily dismounting the door is a perfectly reasonable step if the weight is otherwise unmanageable.)
ADDENDUM:
From your photos and sketch it really looks like if they put the thing up on end, it would be able to go around that corner. "Forearm forklift".or equivalent webbing should make maneuvering it in that orientation straightforward. Unless there is an obstruction I'm not seeing, in which case that obstruction might need to be temporarily dismounted.
"If it happened, it must be possible." If a temporary winch would resolve it, there is space, it's just a matter of how to hold it to use that space.
Second addendum: If the problem is awkward dimensions, neither rails not winch help with that. Removing the wall alongside the bottom steps would. It appears to be nonstructural and only present to make the stairs child-safe, and slapping some simple framing and a sheet of wallboard back in place afterward would be easy and fairly cheap.
I'm underimpressed by your movers. They should have been able to advise, at least.

Any good mover will do exactly what's written here, will shun a customer-built winch, and will bring their own equipment for anything over some limit.  I don't know the limit but it's not 250 lbs.

@jay613 Most importantly, any halfway reasonable (not necessarily good) mover will refuse to bet the safety of their workers on a contraption hacked together by a customer.

If you want to keep it intact, taking the door off is a reasonable way to get more places to grip.  But  strip out any internal dividers etc. so they don't come loose and you're not tempted to grab them

My plan was to move the door and hinges anyway, but movers have already tried getting it up the stairs and around the corner and they couldn't. The space is extremely restricted, with a 1/2" clearance on rotation at the corners, and they'd have to lift it up over their heads to get it high enough to turn it.

@jay613: wondered about cutting off walls that were just insulation, but I wasn't willing to bet on "usually '. I still want to know whether they tried bringing it up on end, which looks like it or to work. Yes, it's an uneven carry, but doing a strap carry can balance that by adjusting how much slack there is on each side.

@keshlam your caution was correct!   I assumed also some walls were "just insulation" but I just watched a teardown video on youtube, and the evaporator coils completely permeate all four walls.

If they can lift it over heads, whatever technique is needed to get it ought should be possible.  Did they remove the cover first?

@keshlam According to the dimensions in OP's drawing, the thing is two inches taller than it's wide, so tipping it on end makes it harder to negotiate the corner, not easier.

@TooTea: Ah. Missed that and photo suggested otherwise. Which brings me back to taking out the wall at the turn and rebuilding it afterward, or slicing it if it can be confirmed that can be done safely. The former strikes me as easier.

... But if the problem is negotiating the turn, a hoist and a track won't help.

@keshlam I think the OP's idea with the hoist was to get it above the ledge, as it needs to be high to make the turn

and "Which brings me back to taking out the wall at the turn" I think should be"...taking back out the wall..." - it looks newer than the rest of the construction (though not as new as some of the wood used for storage) and quite possibly newer than the freezer.  That corner not being there would answer how it got in

@ChrisH: If there is no other solution, I concur. But I don't think that's an essential word for the current issue.

@keshlam not essential, but my view on how the situation came about and how it can be summed up

There are harnesses available (typically called something like "moving harness" or "appliance harness" or "shoulder dolly") that let two reasonably fit people maneuver full-sized refrigerators fairly easily. I would look into something like that long before trying to jury rig anything that could be described as a "hoist and track" system.
As others have mentioned, you'll want to remove the lid (should be a matter of a couple of screws, possibly under a decorative cap) and any feet your unit might have. The lid will obviously reduce the weight, but it will also reduce the size (as will removing the feet), making it easier to transition that corner. And of course, you'll want to have the thing standing upright, on edge, to minimize the horizontal size.

And tip the thing up on its end (minimize horizontal size), so that it's easier to get around the corner.

@Huesmann I kind of figured that went without saying, but...

Sometimes common sense...isn't.

I have used one of those 2-person harnessses and they are borderline magical.

Those moving harnesses look great but do take a bit of space to manoeuvre.  A moving company would have something like that available, as well as alternatives

@ChrisH Many home improvement stores have something like that available. Amazon has something like that available.

@T.J.L. I know but a moving company would have more suitable methods for tight spaces, that wss my point (while acknowledging that they could use this if space allows)

@Huesmann According to the dimensions in OP's drawing, the thing is two inches taller than it's wide, so tipping it on end makes it harder to negotiate the corner, not easier.

@TooTea The drawing was not part of the question when this answer was written.

@T.J.L. Sure, I know that, but that doesn't make the recommendation to tip it over any less outdated

Is it small enough to put in a stair-climbing (tri-wheel) sack-barrow?
You should be able to hire one.
image from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stairclimber


At this point, being careful not to cut near the refrigerant lines, I would actually chop chunks out of it until it fits.  A V-shaped notch in the front (assuming all the active parts are at the back) would be a great help and not make it too structurally weak.
I'd use a metal blade in a jigsaw, or a sabre/reciprocating saw (Sawzall) again with a blade for metal; if the walls are thick the latter might be necessary.
Or, with coils all round, either get the refrigerant circuit emptied in situ and dismantle, or bend/cut/remove the outer  walls, bending the coils or their connecting pipes gently.

What is the comments elsewhere suggests that, unfortunately, there may be refrigerant coils in all four sides.

@keshlam that was added after I wrote the answer; it's why I added the last paragraph

agree, hire a company make sure their insurance is good and you're co-insured!!! also at the minimum cut the lid off... you could hire an appliance servicer to remove the freon most likely it's only 5 oz then cut the unit up

I don't think you need to cut the lid off—some careful disassembly should be sufficient.

Lid and hinges can be unscrewed, that's no problem. It's the narrowness of the stairs and corner the freezer needs to be maneuvered around. unless someone on the bottom is strong enough to lift the chest all the way up over their head while the top guy helps maneuver it around the corner, it won't fit.

We're not a discussion forum. Answers shouldn't be posted which simply "agree" with other answers. Please take the [tour] and see [answer].
